# Getting absolute path without resolving symlinks in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

There are many examples of resolving the path of a file while following symlinks, and I'd like to get the absolute path to a file **without resolving symlinks**.  I think this is the solutions:

```
 ex=Path('example.txt') 
 abs_ex = ex.parent.resolve()/ex
```

Is there something I'm missing in terms of another function or argument to `resolve()`?

There is an answer regarding using os.path.abspath but I'm asking about pathlib in Python 3.6 or better.

Comment: could you elaborate on the not resolving symlinks part. A detailed answer to that would depend on OS an possibly the specific filesystem in use.

Comment: If this question is really about symlinks then it's not duplicate of the one above. If it's not really about symlinks then the link in the comments here would cover it.

Comment: As tagged this question is about the pathlib and is not a duplicate of the os.path.abspath() answer.

Comment: Sorry this question got marked dupe, I agree that it's not and put in into the re-open queue for re-review. thanks for your patience Ray :-)

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt Did they decide this is a dup?

Comment: The answer this is marked as a "dupe" of is about an operating system that doesn't even have the feature this question is about, namely symlinks. It was marked as a dupe and clearly is not. I'll nominate it for reopening and i edited it to put the differentes in **bold** and state them twice.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt: The dupe target is OS-agnostic. The example merely happens to be a Windows path. The answer in the dupe target does not resolve symlinks, regardless of OS. (Also, Windows has symlinks.)

Comment: Regarding the pathlib aspect, the closest pathlib comes to supporting this is the [undocumented, untested, needs-fixing, considered-for-deprecation `Path.absolute()` method](https://bugs.python.org/issue29688). Relying on this method is of course a terrible idea. `os.path.abspath` is a much better option.